# Swinging lower body in pull-ups

Tags: pull-ups

Sometimes my lower body swings when I'm doing pull-ups. Is it bad to swing the lower body when doing pull-ups? Are there any benefits to keeping it immobile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Stop Swinging On Pull-Ups?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/how-can-i-stop-swinging-on-pull-ups)

Answer (score 3):

Involuntary swinging of the lower body during a pull up is usually a mark of low core strength.

Try to reduce the swinging but you really shouldn't force it to be immobile as that could lead to other complications. But do try to work hard on your core strength. Swinging during the pull up reduces the effect on the muscles you want to be targeting (as @JohnP notes in his comment).

Comment: Core strength as in the abdominals?

Comment: The core includes the abs, but also a lot more. See this link for a bit more details.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(anatomy)  Very roughly speaking, everything (both in the front and the back, and also the sides) below the level of the pectorals (chest) and above the quads (thighs) is the core.

Answer (score 2):

Google kipping pull-ups. It uses more of your muscles (hips, lower back) instead of isolating your arms and upper back when you do not swing.

From personal experience, having your lower body (feet) forward will dampen or prevent the swinging.

Comment: It does use muscles in the lower body, but doesn't really stress them. It creates momentum which lessens the work the arms/lats are doing.